# Bad gRPC response when deployed to VM

Tags: c#, iis, grpc

I am working on my first GRPC service and I am running into an issue when I deploy my service to a VM, everything locally works as expected. When I deploy to the VM I get the below response.

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unknown", Detail="Bad gRPC response. HTTP status code: 500")
   at ProtoBuf.Grpc.Internal.Reshape.UnaryTaskAsyncImpl[TRequest,TResponse](AsyncUnaryCall`1 call, MetadataContext metadata, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/protobuf-net.Grpc/Internal/Reshape.cs:line 289
at myGRPC.client.Mehtod(params) in myclient.cs:line 24
...
```

Below is my server configuration:

- Windows Server 2022 (21H2)
- IIS 10
- IIS Installed Features
- Common HTTP Features
- [X] Default Document
- [X] Directory Browsing
- [X] Static Content
- [ ] HTTP Redirection
- [ ] WebDAV Publishing
- Health and Diagnostics
- [X] HTTP Logging
- [ ] Custom Logging
- [ ] Logging Tools
- [ ] ODBC Logging
- [ ] Request Monitor
- [ ] Tracing
- Performance
- [X] Static Content Compression
- [ ] Dynamic Content Compression
- Security
- [X] Request Filtering
- [ ] Basic Authentication
- [ ] Centralized SSL Certificate Support
- [ ] Client Cert Mapping Auth
- [ ] Digest Auth
- [ ] IIS Client Cert Mapping Auth
- [ ] IP and Domain Restrictions
- [ ] URL Auth
- [ ] Windows Auth
- App Development
- [ ] .NET Ext 3.5
- [X] .NET Ext 4.8
- [ ] App Init
- [ ] ASP
- [ ] ASP.NET 3.5
- [X] ASP.NET 4.8
- [ ] CGI
- [X] ISAPI Ext
- [X] ISAPI Filters
- [ ] Server Side Includes
- [X] WebSocket Protocol
- Management Tools
- [X] IIS Management Console
- [ ] IIS 6 Management Compatibility
- [X] IIS Management Scripts and Tools
- [X] Management Service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research I have found that .Net 6 + IIS + gRPC do not agree with each other. I ended up making the service a hosted service and now I can call my gRPC service on the VM.